# How can I solve the conflict issue in refcheck and bookmark packages

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, bookmarks, refcheck

I am using `refcheck` package to check which equation is not cited in my paper. However, it is conflicted with a package "bookmarks". How can I solve that issue, but still use `bookmark` package

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
1-1=0
\end{equation}

The Eq. (\ref{eq:1}) is cited.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `refcheck` after `bookmark`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`refcheck` needs to hook into `\ref` and other, related commands, which isn't possible anymore, if those commands are changed later on (and again) by `hyperref` and `bookmarks`:

Solution: Load `refcheck` **after** `bookmarks`

`refcheck` is one of the rare packages that must be loaded after `hyperref` etc.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
1-1=0
\end{equation}

The Eq. (\ref{eq:1}) is cited.
\end{document}
```